# 2 x 2 x 2 interaction... need to report the 2 x 2 as well?

Tags: repeated-measures, interaction

I am currently running a repeated measures cross-over design in which participants are completing a cognitive task before and after two different conditions. This cognitive task also has two trial types. Because I was interested in the effects of the condition on cognitive changes, I included the CONDITION * TIME interaction and the CONDITION * TIME * TRIAL TYPE interactions.

My questions are: 1) do I need to include the other 2 x 2 interaction (e.g., TIME * TRIAL TYPE) even if that is not the primary outcome of interest, and 2) if I observe a significant CONDITION * TIME * TRIAL TYPE, do I still need to report the CONDITION * TIME interaction regardless of p-value?

Thank you so much!